# Start Activity from RecycleView Adapter on click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I have an issue starting a new activity from a CardView Adapter, this is the code:

```
RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(array_restaurants);
recList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And after in the adapter. I set an OnClickListener

```
personName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                System.out.println("Context");
                System.out.println(context.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Restaurante.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

When i print the context in the console everything looks fine, but after the aplication stop working. Why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() only instead of v.getContext

Comment: Please show log cat result

Comment: Hi. I have no access to that method in the v variable, how can i access to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time I found an answer, the answer that those people submit help me to found the main problem, this was the solution

In the MainActivity I added a new parameter and pass the activity to the adapter, like @Meenal Sharma and @ch3tan proposed

```
RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(restaurantes, this);
```

And in the adaptor

```
  public Adaptador(List<Restaurant> restaurants, Context context) {
    this.restaurants = restaurants;
    this.context = context;
}
```

And creating the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

That part solve an error but the main error that i had was, when I created a new activity with the Android Studio that created the new activity inheriting of ActionBarActivity, I changed ActionBarActivity for AppCompatActivity and everything worked again...

Answer (score 0):

pass context of your activity in which you had set adapter

```
Context mContext;

//write this line in oncreate

   mContext=this; 
   RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(array_restaurants,mContext);
   recList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then in your adapter class use this context in place of v.getContext()

```
Context context;

RVAdapter(your array,Context mContext)
  {
    context=mContext;
  }
```

and use it like

```
personName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("Context");
            System.out.println(context.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Restaurante.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

it may ask to cast context in startActivity with Acitivity you can do that.

Comment: Hi I implemented your code but i got this error:
non static field 'context' cannot be referenced from a static context, so I convert context to static, but now I still getting this excepcion when I tried to start the activity:


unimagdalena.edu.co.restaurantes I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:unimagdalena.edu.co.restaurantes time:8967504
unimagdalena.edu.co.restaurantes W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41852ce0)

Comment: can you provide your whole code..so that it help me to understand your problem clearly..

Comment: MainActivity:
https://gist.github.com/miguelcrespo/78ba688fd6179f4b0d49

Adapter:
https://gist.github.com/miguelcrespo/5652f34d55c79a991a06

Comment: write this globally before on Create  Context mContext; and mContext=this inside onCreate

Comment: Also can you provide your log cat stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Activity object to your adapter not Context object.
I saw your code.
Replace this code at these lines
MainActivity.java

```
Line 68:  RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(restaurantes, MainActivity.this);
```

RVAdapter.java

```
Line 21: Activity mActivityContext; 

Line 55-58: RVAdapter(List<Restaurante> persons, Activity mActivityContext) {
        this.persons = persons;
        this.mActivityContext= mActivityContext;
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem.